# What is the IL(t) of the RL Circuit of the IL(t=0) = I ini

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I have a RL circuit

[image]

I have to find the current in the mash I L(t) so the mesh current but the initial I L(0) = I initial = 3 mAH, now I have the the I(t) when I assumed that t=0 which is:

```
I(t) = Vs/R (1 - e^((-R/L)*t)))
```

Then I have done everything again with the assumption that I L(0) = I ini
and then I have got this equation:

```
I L(t) = Vs/R + (I ini - Vs/R) * e ^ ((-R/L) * T)
```

And then I have the given values: Vs=10V, R=1kOHM, L=1mH and I ini = 3mA

Then I substitute everything but the function is so weird (I also should get the I L(0) = 3mAH, but I dont) and I cannot even procede to do the Euler's explicit interation to plot the results, can anyone tell me if my equation is wrong, if it is can someone explain why and how can I fix it in order to work?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. If you are interested, this site uses MathJAX and you can use it for your equations. See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help. Use `$$` tags to start and end on its own line. Use `\$` tags for inline MathJAX. You will like it.

Answer (score 2):

I wish you'd exposed more details of how you walked through your process. But at least you show some work. Rather than point to an error, I'd rather simply walk through the process as I'd see it, instead.

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFbgKlm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Nodal analysis provides:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_X}{R_1}+\frac{1}{L_1}\int V_X\:\text{d}t&= \frac{V_S}{R_1}
\end{align*}$$

Taking the derivative, I get:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d} V_X}{R_1\:\text{d}t}+\frac{V_X}{L_1}&= 0\\\\
\frac{\text{d} V_X}{\text{d}t}&= -\frac{R_1\:V_X}{L_1}\\\\
\frac{\text{d} V_X}{V_X}&= -\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:\text{d}t\\\\
\int \frac{\text{d} V_X}{V_X}&= \int-\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:\text{d}t\\\\
\operatorname{ln}\left(V_X\right)&= -\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:t+C_0\\\\
V_X &= A_0\:e^{-\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:t}
\end{align*}$$

The initial conditions are that \$V_{X_{t=0}}=A_0=V_S-I_0\cdot R_1\$. So, the above becomes:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X &= \left(V_S-I_0\cdot R_1\right)\:e^{-\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:t}
\end{align*}$$

You know that the current must always be \$I_X=\frac{V_S-V_X}{R_1}\$, so:

$$\begin{align*}
I_X &= \frac{V_S-\left(V_S-I_0\cdot R_1\right)\:e^{-\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:t}}{R_1}\\\\
&=\frac{V_S}{R_1}\cdot\left(1-e^{-\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:t}\right)+I_0\cdot e^{-\frac{R_1}{L_1}\:t}
\end{align*}$$

It is handy to set \$\tau=\frac{L_1}{R_1}\$. Then:

$$\begin{align*}
I_X&=\frac{V_S}{R_1}\cdot\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right)+I_0\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}
\end{align*}$$

If you figure \$\tau=1\:\mu\text{s}\$, \$I_0=3\:\text{mA}\$, \$V_S=10\:\text{V}\$, \$R_1=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$, and plug in \$t=0\$ you will find \$I_{X_{t=0}}=3\:\text{mA}\$ (Also, \$I_{X_{t=1\:\mu\text{s}}}\approx 7.4\:\text{mA}\$ and \$I_{X_{t=2\:\mu\text{s}}}\approx 9.1\:\text{mA}\$, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to '[Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)' in a series RL-circuit:

$$0+\text{V}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)-\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=-\text{V}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Now, we know a few things:

- $$\text{V}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}=\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}\tag2$$
- $$\text{V}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{L}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}=\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$0+\text{V}_{\space\text{R}}\left(t\right)-\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=-\text{V}_{\space\text{L}}\left(t\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$0+\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}-\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=-\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}+\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}+\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}\tag4$$

Using the initial condition, and using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform):

$$\text{v}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{L}\cdot\left(\text{s}\cdot\text{i}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{s}\right)-3\cdot10^{-3}\right)+\text{i}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{R}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{i}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{v}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{L}\cdot3\cdot10^{-3}}{\text{L}\cdot\text{s}+\text{R}}=\frac{\text{v}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{L}\cdot\text{s}+\text{R}}+\frac{\text{L}\cdot3\cdot10^{-3}}{\text{L}\cdot\text{s}+\text{R}}\tag5$$

So, for the inverse Laplace transform you can write:

$$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{L}\cdot3\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{L}\cdot\text{s}+\text{R}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}+\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{L}\cdot\text{s}+\text{R}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\cdot\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau\tag6$$

Where I used the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems).